# Drupal 7 Omega responsive theme. How to disable the mobile breakpoint?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm aware that responsive design is mobile led and what I am trying to do may not be considered responsible. However, I have an omega theme and the previous developer has (or the theme default) is poorly rendering the mobile only version.

When the site is resized to a mobile width, all the content snaps into one column. Until there is time to consult the expertise of UX and Design experts to implement this properly, I want to disable this one column layout. I want the iPhone to display the site like a normal website with pinch to zoom.

Any ideas how I can turn this break point off?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off this via the theme settings. Just go to "Appearance" and click on the settings link next to you omega sub-theme. There in the "Grid settings" switch off the "Fluid layout".

Comment: If that does not work you can always remove the @media style for the iPhone screen resolution in the stylesheet. But try the theme setting option first before you go hacking and slashing.

Comment: @lance The grid systems is already set to "Default 960px" (not "Fluid") :/

Comment: @Cromian I've just done a search in the subtheme and the original omega theme and in the stylesheets, there are on @ media queries. Is this done with JS somehow?

Comment: @Nadine: Are you sure you unchecked the checkbox in the section "Default (960px) layout settings" / "Fluid Layout" / "Use this layout with the responsive grid"?

Comment: @Lance ahhh I see. I've unchecked that and now the site is now permanently in the one column layout, regardless of the browser size. I'm guessing this is now a problem with the CSS? It seems it could be that the correct layout is only applied to the other style sheets and not the first (global) mobile one?

Comment: @Nadine: Difficult to tell. Usually it works this way out of the box. But probably some other stylesheets or something else is doing something. Have you cleared the cache?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to disable the mobile breakpoint with the [breakpoint](https://www.drupal.org/project/breakpoints) module.